# How to set up borders in snake game

Tags: java

I have a snake game set up in Java and I wanted to be able to toggle between the ability to go through the sides and pop out the opposite side and the classic version where you die when you hit the border. The problem is that my snake keeps going one spot after the border, how do I fix this?

This is one of the parts of my code that acts when the right arrow key is pressed:

```
    if(right) {

        for(int i = lengthofsnake - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            snakeylength[i+1] = snakeylength[i];
        }

        for(int i = lengthofsnake; i >= 0; i--) {

            if(i == 0) {
                snakexlength[i] = snakexlength[i] + 25;
            }

            else {
                snakexlength[i] = snakexlength[i-1];
            }

            if(!borderGameplay) {
                if(snakexlength[i] > 850) {
                    snakexlength[i] = 25;
                }
            }

            else {
                if(snakexlength[i] > 850) {
                    borderDead = true;
                }
            }
        }

        repaint();
    }
```

borderGameplay is the variable that you can toggle to have borders on and off and borderDead is used in this IF statement.

```
if(borderDead) {
        if(score > highScore) {
            highScore = score;
        }
        playing = false;
        dead();
        deadGraphic(g);
}
```

dead() and deadGraphic(g):

```
public void deadGraphic(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.BOLD, 50));
    g.drawString("Game Over", 300, 300);

    g.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
    g.drawString("Press \"Space\" To Restart And \"Enter\" To Toggle Borders", 160, 340);

    if(borderGameplay) {
        g.drawString("Borders ON", 370, 380);
    } 
    else {
        g.drawString("Borders OFF", 365, 380);
    }
}

public void dead() {
    right = false;
    left = false;
    up = false;
    down = false;
    dead = true;
    score = 0;
    moves = 0;
}
```

And finally my JFrame:

```
    JFrame obj = new JFrame("Snake");
    gameplay Gameplay = new gameplay(); 
    obj.setBounds(10, 10, 905, 700);
    obj.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    obj.setResizable(false);
    obj.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    obj.add(Gameplay);
    obj.setVisible(true);
```

If you need to see other parts of my code please tell me, because this question is already really long and my total code is 550 lines.

Comment: This question might get a better response from the [Game Development Stack Exchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) channel.

Comment: okay thanks will see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried calling the dead() function 1 pixel before the wall? i.e

```
else {
                if(snakexlength[i] > 849) {
                    borderDead = true;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Just tried it before, the problem is that then the snake dies when it's one "block" from the border (I set it up as a grid of 25 pixels x 25 pixels because the snake body is 25x25 for each part